# How to test my inApp purchase in server model while my one app is live

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I have an iOS app with in APP purchase with server model, and ready for QA submission. According to Apple documents, my server should call "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt" url for testing.

That means till my app is in QA I have to put this url in my server and when my app cleared the review process and ready for sale then I should change my url?

Ok, if that is the case, then how can I test my other application when the previous app is live? I have to create new urls to communicate with the server? I don't think this would be the only way. 
OR
my application should tell my server whether it's a sandbox user or not? If yes, please help me how to check for that in the app.
Please help me if I am missing something.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11740575/1575017