# Which recepit validation URL should be used when submitting to the App Store?

Tags: ios, validation, in-app-purchase, receipt

my app uses Auto Renewable subscriptions and the receipt validation is done from the device. Should I be using the sandbox receipt validation URL or the production receipt validation URL when submitting to the App Store?

Answer (score -1):

Use production references in the App Store submission. The submission is everything you intend to be in the final package that customers get.

Comment: As I understand it, your app will not pass review this way. Reviewers test your app against the sandbox.

Comment: But once they pass your app, what happens? You don't submit another version of the app with a different receipt validation URL, do you? The app that they test is the one that goes on the App Store.

Comment: You first attempt validation against the production URL and if that fails, try the sandbox. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739576/ios-in-app-purchase-will-apple-reviewers-test-live-or-sandbox-environment